# SocketException: No such host is known

Tags: c#, sockets, asp.net-core, mailkit, discountasp

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` app developed on `VS2017 Ver 15.3.3`, I'm using [Account confirmation and password recovery in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/accconfirm?tabs=aspnetcore1x%2Csql-server) and [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) to implement the above article's functionality but I'm getting the following error:

**Note**:

1. The error occurs at line `await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.relay.uri", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None).ConfigureAwait(false);` of `SendEmailAsync(...)` method below and
2. at line `await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account", $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");` of the `Register(...)` post method also shown below:

**ERROR**

> SocketException: No such host is known

**MessageServices.cs class**

```
public class AuthMessageSender : IEmailSender, ISmsSender
{
    public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.
        //return Task.FromResult(0);
        var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

        //You can if required (and I have done in my code) set the LocalDomain used when communicating with the SMTP server
        //This will be presented as the origin of the emails. In my case I needed to supply the domain so that our internal testing SMTP server would accept and relay my emails.
        //We then asynchronously connect to the SMTP server. The ConnectAsync method can take just the uri of the SMTP server or as I’ve done here be overloaded with a port and SSL option. For my case when testing with our local test SMTP server no SSL was required so I specified this explicitly to make it work.
        emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("MyName", "MyEmail@MyDomain.com"));
        emailMessage.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", email));
        emailMessage.Subject = subject;
        emailMessage.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = message };

        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        {
            client.LocalDomain = "smtp.MyDomain.com";
            await client.ConnectAsync("smtp.relay.uri", 25, SecureSocketOptions.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
            await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

**Register post method in AccountController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
            // Send an email with this link
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
            var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ConfirmEmail), "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
            await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Confirm your account",
                $"Please confirm your account by clicking this link: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            _logger.LogInformation(3, "User created a new account with password.");
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Not certain, but the error may be related to me not using my email host info correctly:

1. I'm using a website/email hosting company [DiscountASP.NET](https://discountasp.net/support/)'s webmail feature. Their SMTP Server name for each subscriber is smtp.YourDomainName.com. And hence, in the `SendEmailAsync(...)` method above, I'm using `client.LocalDomain = "smtp.MyDomain.com";`
2. For MailKit implementation I'm following `Sending email via a SMTP server` section of [this](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/how-to-send-emails-in-asp-net-core-1-0) article.

Comment: Have a go at [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961649/no-such-host-is-known-socket-connection). `SocketException` seems to indicate that there is a problem connecting to the configured endpoint in `_emailSender`

Comment: Are you running this code behind company's proxy?

Comment: @BorisModylevsky It's a web/email hosting service `DiscountASP.net`. Do you happen to know if `client.LocalDomain` value would work in that case or `client.LocalDomain` is used only when we are using our company's SMTP? For `MailKit` implementation I'm following [this](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/how-to-send-emails-in-asp-net-core-1-0) article.

Comment: No, I am not familiar with the MailKit package

Comment: The `LocalDomain` property is used as the argument to the `EHLO` or `HELO` command and isn't generally needed unless the auto-detected string that MailKit uses is not accepted by the SMTP server for whatever reason.

Comment: Please Check Your DNS Server Settings. (Get Ping With Command Prompt ).

Answer (score 0):

Open your cmd and write ipconfig /all for windows and search for your hostname of your PC [image: hostname in console]
then enter your Hostname in this function

```html
using (var client = new SmtpClient())
    {
        client.LocalDomain = "smtp.MyDomain.com";
        await client.ConnectAsync("YourHostName", 25,false);
        await client.SendAsync(emailMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await client.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
```