# System.Net.Sockets.SocketException in Visual Studio while using Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send a message to an Event Hub from Visual Studio using C# and I get the below exception.

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'No such host is known'

Any reason why?

Below is the code:

```
namespace EventGenerator
{
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

    public class Program
    {
        private static EventHubClient eventHubClient;
        private const string EhConnectionString = "{EHCONNECTIONSTRING}";
        private const string EhEntityPath = "{EVENTHUBNAME}";

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No such host is known socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961649/no-such-host-is-known-socket-connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the connection to the connection string cannot be build, are you sure that the servers can see eachother (check the firewall settings on azure).

explaination of firewalls within azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Default port number: 1433

Comment: Does it need any particular port to be open for it to send and receive messages?

Comment: Azure databases are ran on different ports per application, you will need to find the port number in the dashboard.
For firewall explaination refer to this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure

Comment: forgot to add, default port is 1433

Comment: I suspect port issue or firewall not letting me post to Event Hubs. I will let you know once I find out why. Thank you.