# C# No such host is known

Tags: c#

When I try to resolve a hostname to an IP address, I get the SocketException "No such host is known".

```
IPHostEntry hostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(_server);
```

I checked [No such host is known socket connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961649/no-such-host-is-known-socket-connection) but no way...
So what's the problem ? I also checked my DNS servers and even pinged the server successfully.

Best regards,
Yannick Allegre.

Comment: Is the reverse DNS set up for the server too? (Although I don't think that should matter really.) If you want to try and investigate then you could try flushing your local DNS cache and then using wireshark or TCP dump to try and see what the DNS request sent (if any) actually is, and compare that to the traffic you see from nslookup or dig, but unless someone can see an obvious error here, or your server is public and you give us the name of the server to try ourselves, then I don't think there's much we can do to help you.

Comment: I checked the nameserver in debugging mode and there was an invisible character "\u0003", the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it to your host file and you will be fine