Dns.GetHostEntry throws 'No such host is known' when executed in a Kubernetes pod
I'm porting a Windows application to Azure Kubernetes and I'm experiencing an issue with this call:
Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName);

practically, when executed in a pod, it throws a SocketException
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known           
  at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) 
  at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)                
  at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)

According to the documentation, dns should be already configured with a default CoreDns plugin and I can also see that two pods are up and running.
What should I do to have Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName) executed correctly in the pod?
I'm taking this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#dns-windows as reference but got nothing so far. Thanks

The Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName) call may fail with a SocketException when executed in a Kubernetes pod due to DNS resolution issues. To troubleshoot this issue, you can follow the steps outlined in the Microsoft documentation on troubleshooting DNS resolution failures from inside the pod but not from the worker node.

Specifically, you can use the nslookup command to test DNS resolution to the endpoint and check whether the DNS requests are being routed to the upstream server. You can also verify that the resolv.conf file has the correct entries and that the upstream DNS server is specified correctly.

Thanks Argo to dive in. I tried with the same test image reported in the documentation and the nslookup returns correctly but, if I do the same for my pod I got kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local can't find kubernetes.default: Non-ex
istent domain

Check these out- https://www.thedummyprogrammer.com/c/system-net-sockets-socketexception-0x80004005-no-such-host-is-known and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961649/no-such-host-is-known-socket-connection

kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local can't find kubernetes.default: Non-existent domain indicates that there could be a DNS resolution issue within your Kubernetes cluster. Check CoreDNS Configuration once
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns


The Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName) method call is attempting to resolve the hostname of the machine (in this case, the pod it is running in) to an IP address.
In a Kubernetes environment, especially when CoreDNS is used, pod names are not automatically resolvable unless you have set up specific DNS entries for them. This is why you may be encountering the "No such host is known" exception.
Another suggestion-
If your application does not strictly require the hostname, you can modify it to work directly with the IP address of the pod. You can retrieve the pod's IP address from the environment variables injected by Kubernetes. You can use- echo $POD_IP  if you're running a command from within the pod and if trying to get it via C# then.
var podIP = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("POD_IP");

To set the POD_IP environment variable in your Kubernetes pod spec, you would add something like the following to your pod's container spec:
env:
- name: POD_IP
  valueFrom:
    fieldRef:
      fieldPath: status.podIP

Then, once this environment variable is set in the pod's specification, your application within the pod can correctly execute Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("POD_IP") to get the pod's IP address.
Similar issue
Similar issue

Thank you so much for the detailed answer. I can try to combine the two solutions because I've a script executed when the container starts so I can retrieve the POD_IP and update the host file with pwsh commands. I think it could be a good workaround until I find out how to do that properly

I'm doing a deeper investigation and maybe found the reason.
The etc/hosts file is filled with an entry like '10.xxx.xxx    gms-1234-6bdd9df76-pkl9d' but the [Environment]::MachineName (that suppose is the pswh equivalent for Environment.MachineName) return the short version of it, in my case 'gms-1234-6bdd9d'. So that's the reason why the dns name cannot be resolved because there is this name-mismatch

I fixed the issue. Practically the netbios name is truncated to 15 bytes so I set the hostname to a short string in the pod spec definition. Thanks so much for your time

That's great to know.
